# Asp.net identity encrypt password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

I am using asp.net identity  and need to encrypt password to compare it to  PasswordHash which exist in to the database.

This is my code :

```
 var passHash = new PasswordHasher().HashPassword("123456");
 using (EFDbContext _db = new EFDbContext())
 {
    var users = _db.Users.Where(u => u.PasswordHash == passHash);
 }
```

I am getting an empty result, but in the database exist the user who has password "123456"

Comment: Why do you access user data manually? If you using Identity,you already have dedicated wrappers and managers: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity . And why do you select user by his password? what if multiple users have same password?

Comment: In one case i  need to access user data manually

Comment: It is just an example to show you what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password hashes are usually compared using the method VerifyHashedPassword from the PasswordHasher class which is why your code is not working, check this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.passwordhasher.verifyhashedpassword(v=vs.108).aspx#M:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(System.String,System.String)

If you have to retrieve users using that password, I think that you can't do it using EF (It can't translate the VerifyHashedPassword method to an sql query), you would have to retrieve all users and compare the password for each one.

If you only want to retrieve a single user I would do the search by email and compare the password using VerifyHashedPassword.